# JQuery form validation on clicking Submit, check all input fields are empty and show innerHTML error not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a form validation using HTML and JQuery to check that all the input fields are not empty when a "Submit" button is clicked. If any of them are empty, the Submit button will not process the form, and will change the color of the empty input fields to Yellow and display a message at the bottom of the form (using innerHTML in a .

This are the relevant HTML codes:

```
<body>
<div id="div_main">
    <form action="process.html" method="POST">
        <div id="div_left">
    <p>Name:</p>
    <p>Age:</p>
    <p>Gender:</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div_right">
        <p><input type="text" id="name" name="name"></p>
        <p><input type="text" id="age" name="age"></p>
        <p><input type="text" id="gender" name="gender"></p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="chksubmit" value="submit"/>
    <div id="divmessage"></div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

And these are my relevant JQuery codes to perform the validation:

```
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chksubmit').click(function(){
        if($('#name').val()==''){
            $('#name').css('background-color','yellow');
            $('#divmessage').append("Please enter Name.")
            success = false;
        }
    });

    $('#chksubmit').click(function(){
        if($('#age').val()==''){
            $('#age').css('background-color','yellow');
            $('#divmessage').append("<br>Please enter Age.")
            success = false;
        }
    });

    $('#chksubmit').click(function(){
        if($('#gender').val()==''){
            $('#gender').css('background-color','yellow');
            $('#divmessage').append("<br>Please enter Gender.")
            success = false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

When I click the Submit with empty input boxes, the form still goes through instead of stopping. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#chksubmit').on("click", function(e) {
    //clean divmessage
    $('#divmessage').html("");
    //or use $("#div_main form input") to check all inputs
    $("#name, #age, #gender").each(function() {
      $(this).css('background-color', '');;
      if ($(this).val().replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim() == '') {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
        success = false;
        $('#divmessage').append("<br>Please enter " + $(this).data("for"))
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div_main">
  <form action="process.html" method="POST">
    <div id="div_left">
      <p>Name:</p>
      <p>Age:</p>
      <p>Gender:</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div_right">
      <p><input type="text" data-for="Name" id="name" name="name"></p>
      <p><input type="text" data-for="Age" id="age" name="age"></p>
      <p><input type="text" data-for="Gender" id="gender" name="gender"></p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="chksubmit" value="submit" />
    <div id="divmessage"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work, except what is the function of the "for" in  $(this).data("for"))? When I try to apply your suggested code fix, user get prompted with "Please enter undefined" instead of the Name/Gender/Age.

Comment: You are welcome, look at HTML there is `data-for="Name"` `data-for="Age"` `data-for="Gender"`